# Function chmod in windows os no like in linux

Tags: php, linux, windows, chmod

PHP:
when I chmod 777 file in windows, it translates into 33060.
i want to create function convert 33060 to 777.
Like this

```
function convertperm($num) {
//do something
}
```

and use:

```
echo convertperm(33060); //return 777
```

Can you help me. Thank you!

Comment: What ? There's a chmod in Windows ? Or did you forget to add a language tag ?

Comment: i use wampserver. and use chmod($filepath, 0777);

Comment: OK, I added the PHP tag.

Comment: but when I checked back it's 33060

Comment: We need more code, and especially how you really call chmod.

Comment: But you might be looking for `octdec`.

Comment: i want convert permission value in windows to value like in linux :D example: 33060 ~ 777 :D thank

Comment: Which function gives you 33060?

Comment: i use wampserver on windows os. and use chmod($filepath) :(

Comment: I see the value of chmod on windows is not the same on linux. so i want to convert these values ​​equal to each other

Comment: Windows and Linux have completely different permissions systems. I'm not sure it's even possible to have this kind of mapping.

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the permission bits from the input in octal, so if file permissions on Windows worked the same as on Unix this would work for you:

```
function convertperm($num) {
    return 0777 & decoct($num);
}
```

However, Windows is not Unix: The execution permission you get from `stat` [depends on the file name extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx). The Windows version of `chmod` [can only be used to make a file read-write or read-only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z319a54.aspx); you can't remove the "read" permssion. Also, there are no separate permissions for "owner", "group", or "other" since the Unix concept of user groups does not exist on Windows.

For example, for `33060` the above function return `444`, indicating read-only permissions. If you had set the permissions to 777 in theory you should get back 666 (Windows chmod ignores the execute bit), so there's probably a bug on your end. Make sure that you [use an octal constant when you call `chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php):

```
chmod($filename, 0777);
```